# Flask [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, json, flask, ubuntu-18.04

I have a flask app which uses a json file to store some config data. That .json file stores at the same location(directory) as the flask app file(app.py) is located. This flask app works fine in the local machine. But when I deploy to a live server (Ubuntu VPS), I'm getting a WSGI error says that

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'config.json'
```

my code is for the .json file as follows

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import json
import random

with open('config.json', 'r') as c:
    par = json.load(c)["par"]
```

What is the wrong with this and how to fix ?

Comment: Are you sure you deployed the json file with the rest ? Try to `print(os.listdir('.'))` to see where you are

Comment: server may run it in different folder, as different user, with different privileges - most for security reason. You may need to use full path to file.

Comment: I tried with this. But same issue.

json_data = os.path.join('config.json')
with open(json_data, 'r') as c:
    par = json.load(c)["par"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help, change the name of your app.py to __init__.py
or just create an empty __init__.py file in the same directory as your app.py file. There is plenty of explanation for this here:

[What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Comment: did you try the full path to file?

Comment: if you change the 'r' to an 'wb' run the code and then change it back to 'r' it will work, I know i tried it.

Comment: it works after adding this: 

json_data = os.path.join('/var/www/webApp/webApp/config.json')
with open(json_data, 'r') as c:
    par = json.load(c)["par"]

But now I can't use the flask app inside my local computer.

Comment: Nothing worked. error log says '/config.json' not found. Then I renamed the file 'config.json' to '/config.json' using FileZilla. Then that file disappeared and the application (site) works fine. I don't know what happened. But now it works.

Comment: I recreated the problem again to see if I could get to the bottom of this. I'm using Visual Studio. The solution is this: the working directory of your terminal has to be the same as the directory your files are in. For instance my python file and config.json file are in C:\a\b\c\folder then I must run the python file when my terminal's working directory is also C:\a\b\c\folder. If you don't do this you get a file not found error. Please confirm and mark as solved.

Answer (score 0):

put that file in static directory
Change path of file.

```
with open('static/config.json', 'r') as c:
    par = json.load(c)["par"]
```